# When using make, should an object file depend on its own header file?

Tags: c, header, makefile, dependencies, object-files

The question is: for `foo.c`, a `.c` file used elsewhere in a larger project, should the `foo.o` object file compilation target in the Makefile list `foo.h` as a dependency?

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

Is this simply a matter of convention?

This is my thinking up until now, and a stab at an answer:

It seems like any legitimate change to `foo.h` would require a corresponding change to `foo.c`. So, it's not necessary to list `foo.h` as a dependency. However, it's probably a good idea, since we'd want to be notified immediately (via re-compilation) if changing `foo.h` broke anything in `foo.c`.

Comment: from what i know if you define rule something.o the make will automatically build something.c with something.h as dependancie, you can check it though.

Comment: There are various changes to a header that require a source file be rebuilt but don't require code changes.  e.g. updating a `#define` or re-ordering members of a structure.  Treating the header as a dependency allows appropriate code to be rebuilt automatically.

Comment: Gnu make will implicitly add the corresponding `.h` file to the dependencies. It is part of the default [suffix list](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html). You will have to overwrite this rule explicitly if you don't want it to be part of the dependencies.

Comment: Lucas: that is not true.  Headers are not added automatically by default rules.  That would be disaster, because it's definitely not a requirement that every source file have a corresponding header file.  Many do not.

Comment: @MadScientist: You appear to be right, headers are not in the default rules. But I don't think adding them to the default rules would be disastrous. If the `.h` file is missing it will just be ignored. You could add it too the rule as follows: `%.o: %.c %.h $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<` (with a linebreak after `%.h`, but comments won't let me do that).

Comment: It absolutely will _not_ be ignored.  Make cannot ignore a defined prerequisite!  What will happen is that since there is no file that matches the `%.h` prerequisite, and make doesn't know how to build one, make will decide this implicit rule does not match and go on to try the next implicit rule.  If there's no other rule that matches, make will fail saying no rule to make target foo.o.  What would work is for make to declare two implicit rules: first one with the `%.h` prerequisite then another one without.  However, it doesn't do that and there's no real point IMO.

Comment: @MadScientist: You are most likely right. Sorry, for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite possible to have changes to header files that don't require changes to the .c files.  For example, changing the values of constants, etc.

You always want to put all header files used by the source file as a prerequisite of the object file.

Comment: Ah, the use of constants (as you've indicated) is a good example that sheds some light on the situation. That's the sort of thing I'm looking for... can you (or anyone else) think of any others?

Comment: Macros in C that take the place of inline functions in C++.

Comment: Some changes to types may not require code changes; for example int to unsigned or vice versa.  Adding or removing #include in the header file may not require code changes.  Obviously in C++ there are a LOT more opportunities.

Comment: One more I just thought of: rearranging the members of a struct.